# Grep on a file that is being written by another application

Tags: linux, bash, file, io, grep

I am using grep to match a string in a file but at the same time another application might be writing to the same file.

In that case what will grep do.

Will it allow the file to being written by other application or will it not give access to the file?

Also if it does give access will my grep results be based on before the file was written or after?

Basically I want the grep to not lock the access to the file but  if it does that is their an alternative to prevent it from doing so..

My Sample command:
egrep -r -i "regex" /directory/*

Comment: AFAIK, grep won't lock the file, it just reads the lines. Grep will read up to where the file is when it finishes

Comment: So you  are saying that the other application will still be able to write to it when grep is running?

Comment: Yes, it will continue writing to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` does not lock the file, so it is safe to use it, while the file is being actively used by another application